# Installing GDAL Python Libraries with Anaconda on Windows 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, gdal

I have Python 3.9 and Anaconda 3 installed and I am trying to install the GDAL library without any luck. I've tried all of the install options on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal and also tried downloading 3.6.2 from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files and installing within conda, but my Python script keeps returning "No module named 'gdal'".

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried with `from osgeo import gdal` ?

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get the command line utilities when the environment is activated? For example run `where gdalinfo` in command prompt, it should show the path to the environment you installed it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I had to set up and activate the environment within Conda and now it works.

```
conda create --name pygdal
conda activate pygdal
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```